# Python Pandas Create Column Based on a Function Requiring to Filter the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a larger script with multiple functions. In one of those functions I am creating a dataframe and then creating a column applying a separate function.

The function to create dataframe at a high level:

```
def data(file):
  df = pd.DataFrame('A': [1,2,3,4], 'B':[5,5,6,6]
  df['C'] = df['B'].apply(func)
```

The 'func' function essentially is supposed to filter the dataframe by column B and return the list of values in column 'A'

```
def func(x):
  df2 = df[df['B']==x]
  names = df2['A']
  return names
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use a global call to retrieve df into the func so I am confused how to perform this request. The ideal out put should be as such:

```
A B C
1 5 [1,2]
2 5 [1,2]
3 6 [3,4]
4 6 [3,4]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `map` after `groupby.apply` (PS: Not recommend using list in column , which will make adjustment harder)

```
df['C']=df.B.map(df.groupby('B').A.apply(list))
df
Out[872]: 
   A  B       C
0  1  5  [1, 2]
1  2  5  [1, 2]
2  3  6  [3, 4]
3  4  6  [3, 4]
```